# How can I speed up a loop which uses numpy.where on a large pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pandas, numpy

The code I've written works correctly but I have a speed problem...

One function (below) is called nearly 10 000 times and takes 0.4+secs each time on my machine, meaning the script itself takes about 66 minutes - too long to be useful. Is there a significantly faster way of writing this 'countifs' like function for Python-3.x? (excel equivalent, for context)

I have an input of c.800 000 rows and 50 columns, this is read into a pandas dataframe (df). All well and good so far. I'm only interested in four columns: 'dateA', 'dateB', 'theme' and 'category'.

I feed the function with individual dates over and over again (generated elsewhere) - for example, between 2013-01-01 and 2017-12-31 ('specifiedDate'); this is the source of c.2000 calls to the function. For each 'specifiedDate' there are five categories (provided by 'a') multiplying the 2000 calls by 5! I'm attempting to rapidly count the number of rows in df which match a provided criteria (in np.where()) for each date and category.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def loopthroughdates(specifiedDate, a):
    df['calc'] = np.where((df['category'] == a)
                        & (df['dateA'] < specifiedDate)
                        & (df['dateB'] > specifiedDate)
                        | (df['category'] == a)
                        & (df['theme'] == "Blue")
                        & (df['dateA'] < specifiedDate),1,0)
    total = df['calc'].sum()
    return total
```

The function returns an integer equal to the number of rows which match the criteria in np.where() for each date and category. This integer is used in the rest of the script to build up a table which looks like the below:

```
Date,cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5
2015-04-10,100,300,80,30,250
2015-04-11,101,300,70,35,248
2015-04-12,102,298,72,38,247
```

I've tried a number of approaches using bits and pieces from other questions on this site but can't find one quicker than this, I feel there must be - can you help?

---

**Edit**

The function is called by a nested for loop:

```
for specifiedDate in datelist:
    for a in categorylist:
        total = loopthroughdates(specifiedDate, a)
```

A sample of df (5 rows) excluding the irrelevant(?) columns - remember this is over 800 000 rows and 50 cols:

```
dateA,dateB,category,theme
2015-01-01,2015-05-10,cat2,blue
2015-04-11,2015-04-13,cat2,blue
2015-02-25,2015-06-01,cat5,red
2015-08-01,2015-08-15,cat1,blue
2014-10-10,2015-09-03,cat4,blue
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you call this function, with some sample input?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Edited. I hope that helps unpick it